# Log of cron.daily?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have a couple of cron jobs in cron.daily which are supposed to execute daily. I know these tasks get executed as I can see the end result. For example: I'm doing a back-up of MySQL DB and I can see the back-up file. However, I cannot find the log for this.

- I checked `/var/log/syslog` with a `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` command all I can find is php5 session clean cronjob(I don't really know what that is)

**Where can I find the log for cron.daily?**

Comment: Mailed to root account, like all cron job output. If you want explicit logging, write to a log file in your code yourself.

Comment: @Amadan The /var/mail directory is empty.

Answer (score 18):

All cron jobs (in a Debian based system like Ubuntu) are logged in /var/log/syslog. You are looking for "CRON" in all caps, so first step is to do a case insensitive search:

```
grep -i cron /var/log/syslog
```

Next, syslog may only show the last 24 hours or less meaning you may not see the daily entry in there. Try searching old syslog files as well:

```
zgrep -i cron /var/log/syslog*
```

You should be able to narrow down the results even further using:

```
zgrep -i cron.daily /var/log/syslog*
```

Comment: Great.. thanks! This worked. The last command only gave me last 6 days.  Does it display 6 days/week at a time?

Comment: Unfortunately all syslog files after 6 days are discarded. Take a look into `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` to change this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can just change the rotate value to have more logs.

Comment: You can also change how often it rotates (weekly instead of daily) so that you have 7 weeks instead of 7 days.